# python: _winreg problem

Tags: python, winreg

the windows registry may contain keys whose names with embedded nulls

when i call `_winreg.OpenKey(key, subkey_string_with_embbeded_null)` i get the following error:

```
TypeError: OpenKey() argument 2 must be string without null bytes or None, not str
```

Q1: is the meaning of the error that python _winreg module has a limitation that it cannot open keys whose names have embbeded nulls?

Q2: how do i get around this limitation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: right.

Q2: download and install [win32all](http://python.net/crew/skippy/win32/Downloads.html).